# OAuthException: Error validating verification code

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, servlets

I have created two servlets named `s1` and `s2`.

`s1` forwards requests to

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=41050677*****&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/fb10/s2& scope=publish_stream,create_event
```

In `s2` I am getting the code and redirecting it to facebook success page:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=410506779*********&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html& client_secret=22049dc145289c2dd7**************&code=(extract code form url)
```

But I am getting an error:

```
 {
   "error": {
      "message": "Error validating verification code.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 100
   }
}
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it? I have used `responce.sendredirect();` for redirection.

Answer (score 0):

You are **not** supposed to make a *redirect* to exchange the code for a token – *think* about it for a second, *please* – you are putting your app secret into this URL, so when you *redirect the client* to it, the user could spot it there easily!

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/ says *explicitly* for step *4. Exchange the code for a User Access Token*:

> Once the user has authorized your app, you should make a server **side request** to exchange the code returned above for a user access token.