# Facebook Android Open Graph

Tags: java, eclipse, facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-android-sdk

So I've been trying to integrate Facebook check-ins to my Android app for the past few days & so far I've only been able to get the authentication process & to post to the wall work. I've been stuck with Open Graph for a while now.

I currently have 1 object type & 1 action type created on my Facebook app.

Object Type: Flight

Action Type: Checkin

I'm trying to interact with these objects but I keep getting these errors; Response: {"error":{"message":"(#100) The parameter object is required","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}

for the following code:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();

params.putString("title", flightNumber);
params.putString("description", flightInfo);

                            Utility.mAsyncRunner.request("me/objects/flightinfoapp:flight", params, "POST",
                                    new placesCheckInListener(), null);
```

& when I include "type" as a parameter which is as exactly as generated by the Facebook app's Open Graph code generator, I get this error; Response: {"error":{"message":"Cannot specify type in both the path and query parameter.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500}}

for the following code:

Bundle params = new Bundle();

```
params.putString("type", "flightinfoapp:flight");
params.putString("title", flightNumber);
params.putString("description", flightInfo);

                            Utility.mAsyncRunner.request("me/objects/flightinfoapp:flight", params, "POST",
                                    new placesCheckInListener(), null);
```

Please if anyone could help me out, I'd hugely appreciate it! Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Have you requested appropriate permissions for the graph stories you're trying to publish? http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/open-graph-permissions/

Comment: Yes I have actually, along with the basic permissions I've requested "publish_actions" as well & before I requested that I was getting a different error therefore definitely that's not the problem :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12417594/oauthexception-error-validating-verification-code

Comment: My access token is just fine as well. Though that question isn't really Android related I suppose but yeah I get what you were trying to say.

Any other ideas? :/

Comment: I guess I'm more suspicious of a misuse of the authentication API itself than of an Android specific issue....  but I don't have much more to offer, either.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the help & effort :)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you send the content of the object as the parameter as in

```
{title:flightNumber,description:flightInfo}
```

but you should send the object with its contents as the parameter as in

```
{object:{title:flightNumber,description:flightInfo}}
```